# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: orj.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

Tags: java, exception, jms

I'm facing a simple problem and seek for help.

Here's the **exception message**:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: orj.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: orj.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ReceveurJMS.<init>(ReceveurJMS.java:44)
    at ReceveurJMS.main(ReceveurJMS.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: orj.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Here's my class **`PanelPhoto`**:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelPhoto extends JPanel{
    private BufferedImage bufferedImage;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),null);
    }

    public BufferedImage getBufferedImage() {
        return bufferedImage;
    }

    public void setBufferedImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        this.bufferedImage = bufferedImage;
    }

}
```

Here's my class **`EnvoyeurPhoto`**:

```
public class EnvoyeurPhoto extends JFrame {

    private JLabel jLabelPhoto = new JLabel("Photo");
    private JComboBox<String> jComboBoxPhotos;
    private JButton jButtonEnvoyer = new JButton("Envoyer");
    private PanelPhoto panelPhoto = new PanelPhoto();
    private Connection conn;
    private Destination destination;

    public EnvoyeurPhoto() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel jPanelN = new JPanel();
        File f = new File("photos");
        String[] photos = f.list();
        jComboBoxPhotos = new JComboBox<String>(photos);
        jPanelN.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jPanelN.add(jLabelPhoto);
        jPanelN.add(jComboBoxPhotos);
        jPanelN.add(jButtonEnvoyer);
        this.add(jPanelN, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(panelPhoto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);

        init();
        jComboBoxPhotos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String photo = (String) jComboBoxPhotos.getSelectedItem();
                    File file = new File("photos/" + photo);
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(file);
                    panelPhoto.setBufferedImage(bi);
                    panelPhoto.repaint();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jButtonEnvoyer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {
                    Session session = conn.createSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                    File f = new File("photos/" + (String) jComboBoxPhotos.getSelectedItem());
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    byte[] data = new byte[(int) f.length()];
                    fis.read(data);
                    StreamMessage message = session.createStreamMessage();
                    message.writeString((String) jComboBoxPhotos.getSelectedItem());
                    message.writeInt(data.length);
                    message.writeBytes(data);
                    producer.send(message);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // RQ:si on a pas faitlorsqu'on a crée la session true c-a-d
                // on a transactionnel(false: n est pas transactionnel) dans
                // cette il faut faire session.commit();
                // session.commit();
                // conn.close();

            }
        });

    }

    public void init() {

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "orj.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "sid");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "azerty");


        try {
            Context ctx;
            ctx = new InitialContext(p);
            ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
            conn = factory.createConnection("sid", "azerty");
            destination = (Destination) ctx.lookup("jms/queue/test");
            conn.start();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EnvoyeurPhoto();
    }

}
```

Here's my class **`ReceveurJMS`**:

```
public class ReceveurJMS extends JFrame {
    private PanelPhoto jPanelPhoto = new PanelPhoto();

    public ReceveurJMS() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(jPanelPhoto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "orj.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        // p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:8080");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "sid");
        p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "azerty");



            try {
                Context ctx;
                ctx= new InitialContext(p);

                ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
                Connection conn = factory.createConnection("sid", "azerty");
                Destination destination = (Destination) ctx.lookup("jms/queue/test");
                Session session = conn.createSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
                //conn.start();
                consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(Message message) {



                            try {
                                StreamMessage m = (StreamMessage) message;
                                String nomPhoto = m.readString();
                                int length = m.readInt();
                                byte[] data = new byte[length];
                                m.readBytes(data);
                                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                                BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(bais);
                                jPanelPhoto.setBufferedImage(bi);
                                jPanelPhoto.repaint();
                            } catch (JMSException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }
                });
                 conn.start();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReceveurJMS();

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to some jboss client jars to your application path. Those jars depend of your version of jboss. Refer to the jboss documentation.

Comment: I have already added jboss-client.jar

Comment: what's you version ?  there more one jar to add

Comment: I work with jboss 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok maybe you have an error in your configuration :

```
 p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "orj.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
```

Because **orj**.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory I think the good name is **org**.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

Comment: I am so sorry, I didn't see your comment.